# post-authorize redirect url

Tags: facebook

I am no longer able to edit the post-authorize redirect url field in my app settings and as it still has the old settings it no longer works and no matter what I do with the fields that I can edit it still keeps the old settings and will not work.

Comment: http://numiko.com/labs/?p=315 might have answer to your question.